# What is the best preposition here?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Can you help me understand which preposition is correct here?

Bob created a repository ***on/at/in*** GitHub.

I tried looking in the collocations dictionary, but [Online Oxford Collocation Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com/) doesn't have an entry for "create".

Comment: A repository **on** GitHub. *Create* can take various prepositions. "GitHub" is a website -- one creates a repository **on** a site.

Comment: Both *on* and *at* can be used, although *on* would be [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=article+posted+on%2C+article+posted+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carticle%20posted%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carticle%20posted%20at%3B%2Cc0) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**On** usually fares well with virtual places as with:

on TV

on the radio

on the internet

on the news

on Facebook

on Instagram

etc.